# Prevent two specific websites from being open at the same time

Tags: google-chrome, url

Since I tend to get distracted easily (by multiple unrelated websites) when I'm browsing the Web, I want to find a way to stop some websites from being opened in a new tab when other specific websites are open.

For example: If http://en.wikipedia.org/ is open in one tab, I want to prevent http://facebook.com from being opened in another tab.

Comment: I don't think there are any extensions that will do exactly what you want, but there are quite a few that will help you manage distractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this extension: Controlled multi-tab browsing

[Go to Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kokmfemecmlekdnjllgobeplngdfifie?hl=en-AU)

> Set maximum tabs that can be opened and restrict yourself from opening
> tabs more than the set limit. The multi-tabbed browsing is good. But
> when you find yourself just keep opening too many tabs and using very
> few of those, it is not good.
>
> The habit of opening too many tabs may hamper your system performance.
> Also, you might waste your time just traversing in between the opened
> tabs or managing those using some fancy extension and often learning
> nothing. So, I suggest you to keep some well-judged limit on the
> number of tabs and to adhere use  "Read and Discard" strategy.
>
> Try this extension, set your tab limit and you will really find
> yourself learning more by actually using/reading the webpages rather
> than just managing and traversing the opened tabs.